# Jquery price filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, divider

I want to create a script to filter divs based on the price element from the div

JavaScript price slider is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tjq(document).ready(function() {
            tjq("#price-range").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 1000,
                values: [ 100, 800 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    tjq(".min-price-label").html( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ]);
                    tjq(".max-price-label").html( "€" + ui.values[ 1 ]);
                }
            });
            tjq(".min-price-label").html( "€" + tjq("#price-range").slider( "values", 0 ));
            tjq(".max-price-label").html( "€" + tjq("#price-range").slider( "values", 1 ));

            tjq("#rating").slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 40,
                min: 0,
                max: 50,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {

                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The div is :

```
    <article class="box">
                                    <figure class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
                                        <a title="" href="https://www.bookingassist.ro/test/html/ajax/slideshow-popup.html" class="hover-effect popup-gallery"><img width="270" height="160" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/270x160"></a>
                                    </figure>
                                    <div class="details col-sm-7 col-md-8">
                                        <div>
                                            <div>
                                                <h4 class="box-title"><?php echo $hotelName5;?><small><i class="soap-icon-departure yellow-color"></i><?php echo $hotelAddress5;?>-<?php echo $hotelDestination5;?></small></h4>
                                                <div class="amenities">
                                                    <i class="soap-icon-wifi circle"></i>
                                                    <i class="soap-icon-fitnessfacility circle"></i>
                                                    <i class="soap-icon-fork circle"></i>
                                                    <i class="soap-icon-television circle"></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="five-stars-container">
                                                    <span class="five-stars" style="width: 80%;"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="review">270 reviews</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            <p><?php echo $hotelDescription5;?></p>
                                            <div>
                                                <span class="price"><small>pret/sejur</small>€ <?php echo $hotelPrices[5];?> <br/>
</span>
                                                <a class="button btn-small full-width text-center" title="" href="#">BOOK</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                          </article>
```

As an example i want to create the action as the example from link : http://www.soaptheme.net/wordpress/travelo/?post_type=accommodation&s

Could you please advise me in this or some examples.

Comment: demo doesn't have slider or price in it. How is anyone to follow what it is you want when code in 2 places is different?

Comment: put a demo in jsfiddle.net that includes exactly what you have.